# ORACLE TRIGGER AFTER INSERT + insert into

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need help with trigger.Need Trigger to 
writing to a table ZVIRE_SeznamZmen.After this trigger i always get error with insert.

```
create table ZVIRE(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
NAZEV VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
DRUH VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
JMENO VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);

create table ZVIRE_SeznamZmen(
ID_ int primary key,
NAZEV VARCHAR(30),
DRUH VARCHAR(30),
JMENO VARCHAR(30),
ZMENA_DRUH VARCHAR(30),
ZMENA_DATUM timestamp);

create trigger ZvireInsert 
AFTER insert on  ZVIRE
for each row
begin
insert into ZVIRE_SeznamZmen(ID_,NAZEV,DRUH,JMENO,ZMENA_DRUH,ZMENA_DATUM) VALUES(:NEW.ID_,:NEW.NAZEV,:NEW.DRUH,:NEW.JMENO,'Insert',SYSTIMESTAMP);
END;
```

Error:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/82     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ID_'
```

Comment: Table `ZVIRE` has a column named `ID`, not `ID_`, so your trigger needs to refer to `:NEW.ID`.

Comment: By the way, `VARCHAR2` is the standard Oracle string type. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-DF7E10FC-A461-4325-A295-3FD4D150809E) explicitly says not to use `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, @William is right, it's the underscore:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ZvireInsert 
  AFTER INSERT ON ZVIRE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  insert into ZVIRE_SeznamZmen(ID_,NAZEV,DRUH,JMENO,ZMENA_DRUH,ZMENA_DATUM) 
  VALUES(:NEW.ID,:NEW.NAZEV,:NEW.DRUH,:NEW.JMENO,'Insert',SYSTIMESTAMP);
END; 
/

Trigger ZVIREINSERT compiled
```